# Menu item clicked ... No reaction

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, com, bho, regsvr32

this is a totally newbie question since my field is Java and not C# but I got given the task of building a BHO and have reached a point where I need a menu item (inside the tools menu) to call a function within my code.

I read that I have to declare and implement the IOleCommandTarget interface, which I did. Now I need to register this same class as a COM Object.

Apparently to do that I need to declare a couple of functions with [ComRegisterFunction] but even after doing so I cannot register them with regsvr32. And uppon further inspection with DLL Export viewer the functions do not seem to be there :(

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**

Ok so from the comments I got I suppose that My COM object is registered correctly but still my problem remains: When I click the newly created menu item I have no reaction or way to debug what's really going on.

This is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using SHDocVw;
using MSHTML;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct OLECMDTEXT {
    public uint cmdtextf;
    public uint cwActual;
    public uint cwBuf;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
    public char rgwz;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct OLECMD {
    public uint cmdID;
    public uint cmdf;
}

// Interop definition for IOleCommandTarget. 
[ComImport,
Guid("b722bccb-4e68-101b-a2bc-00aa00404770"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IOleCommandTarget {
    //IMPORTANT: The order of the methods is critical here. You
    //perform early binding in most cases, so the order of the methods
    //here MUST match the order of their vtable layout (which is determined
    //by their layout in IDL). The interop calls key off the vtable ordering,
    //not the symbolic names. Therefore, if you switched these method declarations
    //and tried to call the Exec method on an IOleCommandTarget interface from your
    //application, it would translate into a call to the QueryStatus method instead.
    void QueryStatus(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 cCmds,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] OLECMD[] prgCmds, ref OLECMDTEXT CmdText);
    void Exec(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdId, uint nCmdExecOpt, ref object pvaIn, ref object pvaOut);
}

namespace ANAISBHO {

    [
    ComVisible(true),
    Guid("8a194578-81ea-4850-9911-13ba2d71efbd"),
    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)
    ]
    public class BHO : IObjectWithSite, IOleCommandTarget {

        public SHDocVw.WebBrowser webBrowser;

        public HTMLDocument document;

        public static string BHOKEYNAME = "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Browser Helper Objects";

        private Guid cmdGuid = new Guid("ED016940-BD5B-11CF-BA4E-00C04FD70816");

        private static Bitmap bmpScreenshot;

        private static Graphics gfxScreenshot;


        public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL) {
            document = (HTMLDocument) webBrowser.Document;
        }

        //HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Extensions\{GUID}\CLSID
        private static void RegisterCiteNPLMenuEntry() {
            Console.WriteLine("Registrying the CiteNPL menu entry");
            RegistryKey MicrosoftKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default).OpenSubKey("Software").OpenSubKey("Microsoft");
            RegistryKey ExtensionsKey = MicrosoftKey.OpenSubKey("Internet Explorer").OpenSubKey("Extensions", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            String GUID = @"{C3E1CD69-3928-4b69-ABEC-936CA3A3BAAA}";

            ExtensionsKey.CreateSubKey(GUID);
            RegistryKey GUIDKey = ExtensionsKey.OpenSubKey(GUID, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
            String CLSID_Shell_ToolbarExtExec = @"{1FBA04EE-3024-11d2-8F1F-0000F87ABD16}";
            GUIDKey.SetValue("CLSID", CLSID_Shell_ToolbarExtExec, RegistryValueKind.String);
            GUIDKey.SetValue("MenuText", "CiteNPL", RegistryValueKind.String);
            GUIDKey.SetValue("ClsidExtension", "{c4127d56-7114-46da-a853-6ea1b8a199f7}", RegistryValueKind.String);

            GUIDKey.Close();
            ExtensionsKey.Close();
            MicrosoftKey.Close();
        }


        public void QueryStatus(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, UInt32 cCmds, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] OLECMD[] prgCmds, ref OLECMDTEXT CmdText) {
            MessageBox.Show("query");
        }

        public void Exec(ref Guid pguidCmdGroup, uint nCmdId, uint nCmdExecOpt, ref object pvaIn, ref object pvaOut) {
            MessageBox.Show("Exec");
        }

        private void TakeScreenshot() {
            int height = 1024; //webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
            int width = 1024;  //webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
            //int left = 0;      //webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Left;
            //int right = 1024;  //webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Right;
            System.Drawing.Size browserSize = new System.Drawing.Size(width, height);

            bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            gfxScreenshot = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
            gfxScreenshot.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            bmpScreenshot.Save("c:\\temp.png", ImageFormat.Png);
        }

        public int SetSite(object site) {
            if(site != null) {
                webBrowser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser) site;
                webBrowser.DocumentComplete += new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
            } else {
                webBrowser.DocumentComplete -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_DocumentCompleteEventHandler(this.OnDocumentComplete);
                webBrowser = null;
            }

            return 0;
        }

        public int GetSite(ref Guid guid, out IntPtr ppvSite) {
            IntPtr punk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(webBrowser);
            int hr = Marshal.QueryInterface(punk, ref guid, out ppvSite);
            Marshal.Release(punk);

            return hr;
        }

        [ComRegisterFunction]
        public static void RegisterBHO(Type type) {
            Console.WriteLine("Registering the BHO");

            RegisterCiteNPLMenuEntry();
            RegisterBHOInWindowsRegistry(type);
        }

        [ComUnregisterFunction]
        public static void UnregisterBHO(Type type) {
            Console.WriteLine("Unregistering the BHO");
            UnRegisterBHOFromWindowsRegistry(type);
        }

        private static void UnRegisterBHOFromWindowsRegistry(Type type) {
            RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHOKEYNAME, true);
            string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");

            if(registryKey != null) {
                registryKey.DeleteSubKey(guid, false);
            }
        }

        private static void RegisterBHOInWindowsRegistry(Type type) {
            RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(BHOKEYNAME, true);

            if(registryKey == null) {
                registryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.CreateSubKey(BHOKEYNAME);
            }

            string guid = type.GUID.ToString("B");
            RegistryKey ourKey = registryKey.OpenSubKey(guid);

            if(ourKey == null) {
                ourKey = registryKey.CreateSubKey(guid);
            }

            ourKey.SetValue("Alright", 1);
            registryKey.Close();
            ourKey.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a managed dll, you cannot use either regsvr32 or "DLL Export Viewer".

To register your .Net dll for COM Interop, use [Regasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Ok regasm works, I'm not really sure what it does but it says that it says that "types registered successfully". But then my Exec function is not invoked. Since I'm using VS express I have no real way of debugging the code and figuring out what happens when I click on that menu item button :(

Comment: @Ricky:- Set the path where regasm is located..generally in installation directory tool section.

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't quite understand what you mean... I've done this and also the same but with /codebase: C:\Documents and Settings\RE86508\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ANAISBHO\ANAISBHO\bin\Release>c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe ANAISBHO.dll